# angular.element(ready) function called twice in cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-controller, bootstrapping

The output from the following code:

```
     app.controller('puntenboekjeController', function ($scope) {
             function upd(){
                console.log("test");
             }

             angular.element(document).ready(function() {
                upd();
             });
    });
```

is:

```
test
test
```

In index.js, i don't bootstrap angular (or anywhere else), app is defined in body-tag, i never used onDeviceReady.

Comment: Seems like you have declared `puntenboekjeController` twice either by `ng-controller` or from route defination

Comment: True! If you want, post an answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like controller code is calling twice does mean that you are loading your controller twice either by using `ng-controller` or from the `route` definition of your SPA.